# JQUERY-UI: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've been trying to get a [Jquery UI draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) to work, but I've run into the following error, and I cannot seem to figure out how to fix it.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot error]

-Edit- Here is the code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ 
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        cursor: "move",
            scroll: false,
        stop: function(e , ui) {
            jQuery("#mottox").val($(this).position().left);
            jQuery("#mottoy").val($(this).position().top);
        }
    });
});​</script>
```

Comment: Copy the code and paste it into Notepad++ (or paste it here so we can copy it directly) to look for hidden characters.

Comment: Sometimes, the debugger cannot point the right line of a script problem if it has been loaded through AJAX. Is it the case? BTW, you don't have syntax error in the script above

Comment: Adding the code might not help as "spaces" are the most likely suspect when it comes to weird characters.

Comment: @davehale23 Yes, but if you paste it into certain editors (such as notepad++) it will let you see those odd characters that other editors won't show you.

Comment: @KevinB, I should have been more clear.  What I meant was that adding their code to the question above likely would not help as the weird characters would not be visible.

Comment: @davehale23 Adding their code to the question allows us to copy and paste it into an editor that will show them. Although it would be nice if these characters were visible on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extra character in your code, see below:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ 
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        cursor: "move",
            scroll: false,
        stop: function(e , ui) {
            jQuery("#mottox").val($(this).position().left);
            jQuery("#mottoy").val($(this).position().top);
        }
    });
});?</script>
```

- ^  the `?` before the closing `</script>`

Copy the code below and use it instead:

```
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#draggable3" ).draggable({ 
        containment: "#containment-wrapper",
        cursor: "move",
            scroll: false,
        stop: function(e , ui) {
            jQuery("#mottox").val($(this).position().left);
            jQuery("#mottoy").val($(this).position().top);
        }
    });
});</script>
```

Comment: and what is the extra character?

Comment: @codingbiz the `?` before the closing `</script>`

Comment: Ok. I didn't see it in the OP's post too. I think this should be added to SO features so we don't need special tools to find bugs like this